# Kill a process started with Groovy execute()

Tags: groovy, process

I'm able to run Groovy scripts from Groovy using

> proc = "cmd /c groovy BillingServer.groovy".execute(null, new File("C:\"))

However, I can't find a way to then terminate / kill the process.  `waitForOrKill(1)` and `destroy()` "act" like they've worked, but the external process continues to run. Calling `exitValue()` fails with

> java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited

How do I kill the process I've started?

Comment: something to consider - why not load the script and execute it directly in groovy instead of spawning an external groovy env?

Comment: I needed to be able to start and stop various web services on demand via a Swing GUI. I found that I couldn't shut them down and restart them when they were in-process.  My workaround was to run them as separate processes that I could control individually. If you have a solution, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by removing `cmd /c` from the string to be executed.  It seems that cmd was spawning groovy, so `waitForOrKill()` was killing the cmd process, but the groovy process was left running.  Without the `cmd /c`, I am spawning a groovy process, and `waitForOrKill()` successfully kills it.